# Beans doesn't update in Spring Elements even I add new MVC classes

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, javabeans, dao, element

I'm working on Dynamic Project with Maven in Eclipse.And using spring. I'm working on a tutorial project which already have a MVC classes.Beans only have the original MVC. Spring Elements Beans doesn't update even I add new MVC classes. How can I update spring elements???[I can see Emplooye on Beans but not Operation](https://ibb.co/eKk9yR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild the project and refrsh Project Explorer.

Click somewhere in the project explorer and do **Ctrl-A, then F5**

Comment: FYI: the F5 is the same as right-clicking the project and choosing "Refresh" on the popup menu there. Eclipse won't see filesystem changes you make outside itself until you do that. If you are trying to get new beans loaded AT RUNTIME, let us know and we can discuss, but i will assume 'java guy' is right.

Comment: Oh I solved the problem immediately: Right-click on project and Build Project. Then all the Beans are arrived.

Comment: But when I run my project on server, this time it gives 404-error (The requested resource is not available.)

Comment: Why it happens when I build project or share project on svn or configure my database? I do not change my url. 404 error occurs after a bit change.

Comment: Please send URL. Do you have set @RequestMapping annotation like @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Its not about my url I only clicked "build project" and project started giving 404 error. I saw a guy solved the problem by adding maven dependencies from deployment assembly tab. But I already have maven dependencies.

Comment: Where 404 is coming from? browser?

Comment: I tried it on both firefox and chrome. My web page was occuring just before I Built Project. I cannot understand what is the problem...  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
 public ModelAndView listEmployee(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
  List<Employee> listEmployee = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
  model.addObject("listEmployee", listEmployee);
  model.setViewName("home");
  return model;
 } and url is http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernateCRUD/

Comment: Where is home.jsp? Do have cofig the path for the views? Take the tutorial from the begin you miss something

Comment: As I declared before, my project works until I make some changes. I also succesfully created all the beans and packages(from the beginning of project).project worked but after I add serialversionid into model classes it again give 404 error. (While project works I can only reach to main register page from home.jsp which is employee register page, I cannot reach the register pages which I added).